# Plot multiple RGB images and histogram side by side in a grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv3.0

I have 10 RGB images and I have calculated histograms of its individual channels. I want to plot the images and their RGB histograms on a 10 x 2 grid with 0th-column representing all images and 1st column representing their respective histograms(R,G,B) concatenated.Something like this:

Histograms

[image]

image_source: https://lmcaraig.com/image-histograms-histograms-equalization-and-histograms-comparison/#2dhistogram

I have checked several options online, but still feel I am missing something. My confusion stems from not understanding the complete behaviour of plt.plot vs plt.imshow.

I am using matplotlib and opencv

I have already tried several options. Here is my code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

w=10
h=10
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
columns = 2
rows = 10
color = ('r', 'g', 'b')
for ii in range(1, rows +1):
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, ii)
    img = bad_images_numpy[ii+400,:,:,:] #bad_images_numpy shape-> (4064,64,64,3)
    plt.imshow(img)
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, ii+1)
    for i,col in enumerate(color):
        histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
        plt.plot(histr,color = col)
        plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```

Currently my images and histograms are getting overlayed on each other and I am not able to figure out how to efficiently plot them

Comment: You will find the problem by printing out `ii` and `ii+1` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `plt.subplots()` and `plt.subplot()`, then render histograms/images on the axes, not `plt.imshow()`, or `plt.plot()`.

Here's a similar function I wrote a while back for just the same purpose. This shows histograms on the left, image on the right. I'm sure you can change it to show other way.

```
def histogram_img(img, title=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

    colors = ('b','g','r')
    histograms = []

    for i in range(3):
        hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [i], None, [256], [0,255])
        histograms.append(hist)

        ax1.plot(hist, color=colors[i])


    tmp_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    ax2.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(tmp_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    ax2.grid(False)
    ax2.axis('off')    

    if title is not None:
        plt.title =  title

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, and according to https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/22/clever-girl-a-guide-to-utilizing-color-histograms-for-computer-vision-and-image-search-engines/ , the calculation of hist could be `hist = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])`  , just curious here that why you choose the range of `[0, 255]` but not `[0, 256]` ?

Comment: @tli2020 I vaguely remember I did so because the pixel values are never 256.

Comment: Aha, it seems that we might use `[0, 256]`, refer: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html